# Why does the jQuery .index() method only work for the first element in the collection, when a selector is specified?

Tags: javascript, jquery, indexing

I am trying to build up a table by adding values from textbox fields in the `tfoot` of the same table. The eventual goal is to be able to then inline edit previously added rows while still leaving the capability to add more rows.

I have the following markup:

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Service</th>
            <th>Protocol</th>
            <th>Source Port</th>
            <th>Destination Port</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" data-function="service" value="foo" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" data-function="protocol" value="bar" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" data-function="sourcePort" value="baz" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" data-function="destPort" value="fob" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <button id="addBtn" type="button">Add</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

The below script stores all of the `input[type=text]` elements in the `tfoot` in an inputs variable. From there I am trying to use `.index()` to identify and then retrieve the value of each textbox:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#addBtn').click(function (e) {
        var inputs = $(this).closest('tfoot').find('input[type=text]');
        console.log(inputs);

        var serviceIndex = inputs.index('[data-function="service"]');
        console.log(serviceIndex);
        console.log(inputs[serviceIndex].value);

        // the remaining indexes all return -1

        var protocolIndex = inputs.index('[data-function="protocol"]');
        console.log(protocolIndex);
        console.log(inputs[protocolIndex].value);

        var sourcePortIndex = inputs.index('[data-function="sourcePort"]');
        console.log(sourcePortIndex);
        console.log(inputs[sourcePortIndex].value);

        var destPortIndex = inputs.index('[data-function="destPort"]');
        console.log(destPortIndex);
        console.log(inputs[destPortIndex].value);
    });
});
```

Unfortunately the selector `data-function="X"` selector only works for service. All of the other selectors return `-1` indicating that a value was not found. The above code is from this [jsFiddle which illustrates the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/ahsteele/Dfxy9/). I am not wedded to using index, but cannot use the element's `id` as I need a more general solution.

Why does the [jQuery .index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/) method only work for the first element in the collection, when a selector is specified?

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

> If .index() is called on a collection of elements and a **DOM element** or
>   **jQuery object** is passed in, .index() returns an integer indicating the
>   position of the passed element relative to the original collection.

So this should work:

```
inputs.index($('[data-function="protocol"]'));
...
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Dfxy9/2/

Comment: From the docs as well: _"If a selector string is passed as an argument, .index() returns an integer indicating the position of the **first element**..."_

Comment: that seems totally worthless. So if a selector string matches the first element 0 is returned. If the element is not in the first position -1. Put differently what's the point?

Comment: I think maybe you're missing the point of `index` here... If that's really your code then I'd use either `filter` or `index` on the parent `td`... What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: I am sure I'm missing the point. :) From the docs: *Search for a given element from among the matched elements.* Which I read as passing a string selector to the the index method of a collection should return an element position. [Explosion Pills answer indicates](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14972282/61654) that index does not iterate the collection. Which would mean I'm off the mark. My goal is to accurately retrieve the value of each text box in the tfoot so that I can create a row in the tbody. Then will need to able to modify the values in the newly created row w/ hopefully reusable code.

Answer (score 0):

In the context you are using it `.index` is only called on the *first* element in the jQuery collection.  jQuery does this for any non-iterative method (for example `.html`, `.attr`, `.text`) -- `.index` is no different.

Instead of using the collection, use the selector: http://jsfiddle.net/4kLqb/